# Hide clang warnings using makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I have a makefile with the following lines:

```
CXX=clang++
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wno-c++11-extensions
```

I am still getting this:

`warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

Is there a way that I can hide the warning using the makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### POST QUESTION EDIT

The contents in the original post by [rsay3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182954/rsay3) insufficient to being answered properly. What is not stated in the post is the correct approach which leaves us to only deduce that the problem is actually elsewhere, an elsewhere which is not stated in the question.

If `-std=c++11` is used we should not get any warnings about a certain feature only being available in C++11 (since we are already compiling it as C++11), and the redudant `-Wno-c++11-extensions` is correct (even though uneccessary).

---

#### PRE QUESTION EDIT

`-W...` and an added warning-specifiers *enables* a certain warning, if you'd like to *supress a diagnostic* you will have to use `-Wno-...`, as in the below example:

```
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wno-c++11-extensions
```

---

```cpp
// main.cpp

int main () {
  auto val = 123;
}
```

```
% clang++ -Wall -std=c++03 main.cpp
foo.cpp:2:3: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  auto val = 123;
foo.cpp:2:8: warning: unused variable 'val' [-Wunused-variable]
  auto val = 123;
```

```
% clang++ -Wall -Wno-c++11-extensions -std=c++03 main.cpp
foo.cpp:2:8: warning: unused variable 'val' [-Wunused-variable]
  auto val = 123;
```

Comment: I edited my question to add this but I am still getting the warning

Comment: That line is the only place I have it. How do I use the value where clang is taking place?